# Sum up every 12 months in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have values in the column from `b10` to `b70`. I want to sum up every 12 columns and keep that sum number in different column of cells.

I'm using a if condition here. If that condition is true then I have to sum up every 12 column and store those values in different cells.

here i'm attaching the sample one. f column have the values from f8 to so on.. and the sum up values should store in h column and have a value 40 in c8.

so condition is if(c8=40, then the sum up of every 12 rows in f column from f8:f20, f21:f33 so on and store in h column rows,"")

those sum up values should stored in h column

can u help me please..
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'sum up every 12 column'? Every twelfth column? The example you describe has only one column, so it's unclear what your input and desired output is.

Comment: It would also help to see your current `IF` condition.

Comment: This question seriously lacks sample data, expected results and and evidence of original effort. The contradictory narrative puts it in the 'unclear what you are asking' category.

Comment: i edit the question. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st 12months

```
=SUM(OFFSET($F:$F,MATCH(40,$C:$C,0)-1,0,12))
```

2nd,3rd,4th 12 months

```
=SUM(OFFSET($F:$F,MATCH(40,$C:$C,0)+11,0,12))
=SUM(OFFSET($F:$F,MATCH(40,$C:$C,0)+23,0,12))
=SUM(OFFSET($F:$F,MATCH(40,$C:$C,0)+35,0,12))
```

or 
1st 12

```
    =IF($C$8=40,SUM(OFFSET($F:$F,7,0,12)),0)
```

then just add 12 to 7 for each additional 12 months